# Skin tones shift redder when OBS outputs to virtual camera, then to Google Hangouts

Tags: obs, macbook

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2015 with its internal webcam.
When I use the webcam directly in Google Hangouts, skin tones look normal.
When I use OBS as a virtual camera in Hangouts using the same webcam, skin tones look too  purple/reddish. Anyone know why?